# BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException with PlatformTransactionManager

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception, transactions, autowired

I'm new to Spring and I did a login/register applicaton following a youtube tutorial but I want to add a new functionality that allows to delete a student. I used @Transactional on my delete method and modified accordingly the xml file but I get this error:

```
Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'platformTransactionManager' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' but was actually of type 'com.infotech.service.impl.StudentServiceImpl'
```

my Service class

```
@Service("studentService")
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentDAO studentDAO;

    public void setStudentDAO(StudentDAO studentDAO) {
        this.studentDAO = studentDAO;
    }

    public StudentDAO getStudentDAO() {
        return studentDAO;
    }

    //other methods

    @Override
    public void delete(String email) {
        getStudentDAO().delete(email);
    }

}
```

my DAO class

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Repository("studentDAO")

public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
    }

    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
        return hibernateTemplate;
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return (Session) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    //other methods

    @Transactional("platformTransactionManager")

    public void delete(String email) {
        Student student = (Student) ((HibernateTemplate) getSession()).get(Student.class, email);
        ((HibernateTemplate) getSession()).delete(student);
    }

}
```

In the dispatcher servlet I have defined InternalResourceViewResolver, dataSource, hibernateTemplate, sessionFactory beans and then I added another bean

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="platformTransactionManager"/>

<bean id= "platformTransactionManager"class="com.infotech.service.impl.StudentServiceImpl">
</bean>
```

Finally, this is the controller

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    public void setStudentService(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    public StudentService getStudentService() {
        return studentService;
    }

    //...RequestMappings...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable("email") String email) {
        studentService.delete(email);

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/view/home");
    }

    ...
}
```

Now, how can I make my bean of PlatformTransactionManager type?
But most of all I think there's a simpler way to delete a field from my table, maybe without using @Transaction at all so can anyone help me understand why I get the error and explain me what is @Transactional and if I really should use it in this case? 
Remember that I'm NEW to Spring, I still don't have many notions so sorry if I wrote something totally stupid :-)

Answer (score 0):

Spring is looking for transaction manager - it requires a concrete implementation of the `PlatformTransactionManager` interface. It's being given your service implementation, which isn't a `PlatformTransactionManager` and not what it needs. If you're using JDBC, `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager` should work.

Try changing:

```
<bean id= "platformTransactionManager" class="com.infotech.service.impl.StudentServiceImpl">
```

To:

```
<bean id= "platformTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
```